# Не могу применить команду ls /dev/ | grep sdb1 к QProcess

Tags: qt

Не могу применить команду `# ls /dev/ | grep sdb1` к QProcess. Проверил команду `# ls /dev/ | grep sdb1` в терминале все работает.
Делаю вот так:

```
QProcess* chkproc = new QProcess();
chkproc->start("ls /dev/ | grep sdb1");
chkproc->waitForFinished();
qDebug() << chkproc->readAll() << chkproc->readAllStandardError();
chkproc->close();
```

вот что получаю в отладчики:

```
"/dev/:
block
bsg
bus
char
console
cpu_dma_latency
disk
dri
fb0
fd
full
gpiochip0
gpiochip1
gpiochip2
gpiochip3
gpiochip4
i2c-0
iio:device0
input
kmsg
log
mem
memory_bandwidth
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p1
mmcblk0p2
mmcblk0p3
mtd0
mtd0ro
mtd1
mtd1ro
mtd2
mtd2ro
mtd3
mtd3ro
mtd4
mtd4ro
mtd5
mtd5ro
mtd6
mtd6ro
mtdblock0
mtdblock1
mtdblock2
mtdblock3
mtdblock4
mtdblock5
mtdblock6
network_latency
network_throughput
null
ptmx
pts
random
rtc
rtc0
rtc1
sda
sda1
shm
snd
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
tty0
tty1
tty10
tty11
tty12
tty13
tty14
tty15
tty16
tty17
tty18
tty19
tty2
tty20
tty21
tty22
tty23
tty24
tty25
tty26
tty27
tty28
tty29
tty3
tty30
tty31
tty32
tty33
tty34
tty35
tty36
tty37
tty38
tty39
tty4
tty40
tty41
tty42
tty43
tty44
tty45
tty46
tty47
tty48
tty49
tty5
tty50
tty51
tty52
tty53
tty54
tty55
tty56
tty57
tty58
tty59
tty6
tty60
tty61
tty62
tty63
tty7
tty8
tty9
ttyAMA0
ttyAPP1
ttyAPP2
ubi_ctrl
urandom
vcs
vcs1
vcsa
vcsa1
vcsu
vcsu1
watchdog
watchdog0
zero
"" 
"ls: cannot access '|': No such file or directory
    ls: cannot access 'grep': No such file or directory
    ls: cannot access 'sdb1': No such file or directory
"
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

Comment: Как понял не может Qprocess работать с двумя командами сделал вот так 'chkproc->start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "ls/dev/ | grep sdb1");' но результат не получил.

Comment: попробуйте упрощать, например без grep